# Windows 2008 AD DC across two subnets

Tags: networking, active-directory, routing, domain-controller, subnet

I have two private subnets

- 10.9.1.0/24
- 10.9.137.0/24

The 10.9.1.0/24 was there at first and I created an Active Directory Domain Controller using MS Windows 2008R2 with the IP 10.9.1.10. The router and DHCP Server is 10.9.1.1

A couple of days ago a new Group joined our department and we are now also in control of 10.9.137.0/24. The setup is quite similar, the DHCP Server and router is 10.9.137.1. In order to connect the two networks (they are in two different physical locations) I created a IPsec VPN using a pre-shared key. I then was able to ping from one network into the other. I am also able to use the same DNS service, which happens to be running on the AD (10.9.1.10) from both networks.

Only problem I have is, when I try to ad a Windows 7 PC from the second net (10.9.137.0/24) to the existing DC I get the error that the AD DC cannot be found. It does not work with the FQDN, the DNS-Name nor the IP-address.

I cannot find a reason, as I said, pinging works fine, I can even connect to network-shares from one network to the other.

What am I doing wrong? Does the AD DC need to be in the same subnet (10.9.0.0/16)? Do I need to tell my AD DC that it also "serves" the other subnet?

Any ideas? Any clue in what direction I should look are appreciated.

Thanks,
Stephanie.

Comment: The PC got what as a DNS's server in the NIC's property ? it must be the DC, even if on other subnet it should work

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue. Is the client using a DNS server that can resolve the SRV records from your domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undoubtedly it must be DNS issue.   There is a strange thing which started after the release of Windows Server 2008.  After promoting a "Server" to "Domain Controller" (AD with integrated DNS) the DNS IP changes to loopback 127.0.0.1 in TCP/IP.  Hence, I would suggest to check that and restart DNS Server.  Your issue will probably be fixed.